# Connecting to SQL Server with CL-SQL via unixODBC/FreeTDS

Tags: sql-server

I've managed to connect from SBCL running on debian to an SQL Server 2000 instance over the network using FreeTDS/unixODBC.

I can actually get data back from the server, so all is working.

However, many of the columns trigger what seem to be unsupported data types a-la:

```
The value 2147483647 is not of type FIXNUM.
```

and

```
-11 fell through ECASE expression. 
Wanted one of (-7 -6 -2 -3 -4 93 92 91 11 10 ...).
```

Anyone have experience using CLSQL with SQL Server would be able to help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (error with 2147483647) occurs because the FreeTDS driver doesn't handle OLEDB BLOBs so well.

You have to issue the following SQL command to make it work:

```
set textsize 102400
```

You can see the FreeTDS FAQ entry [here](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#textdata). Excerpt:

> The text data type is different from char and varchar types. The maximum data length of a text column is governed by the textsize connection option. Microsoft claims in their documentation to use a default textsize of 4000 characters, but in fact their implementation is inconsistent. Sometimes text columns are returned with a size of 4 GB!
>
> The best solution is to make sure you set the textsize option to a reasonable value when establishing a connection.

As for the ECASE expression, I haven't really solved it but I have hacked it away by doing a data conversion of `timestamp` into a `binary` value, and a `uniqueidentifier` into a `varchar(36)`.